# setting center_horizintal property as false

Tags: android, layoutparams

I have set align_center_horizontal as true in my layout xml . but sometimes I do want to set as false . I found that there is no FALSE variable as such defined in RelativeLayout so that I can make it false at runtime

If it is possible to achieve how ?

assuming its not possible I created a new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams as below

```
if (digitPadVisible == false) {    
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        String stringDimensions = getResources().getString(
        R.dimen.active_call_options_margin_bottom);
        params1.bottomMargin = Integer.parseInt(stringDimensions
}else{
...
...
}
```

but the effect of making this change is not visible when  digitPadVisible is false , instead it is visible in the digitPadVisible true case

I think applying LayoutParams is not taking immediate effect how can I solve this

Comment: So you're trying to change the alignment in a RelativeLayout, is that it? I'm not quite sure what you're asking exactly.

Comment: yeah I am trying to change the alignment .